# How would the fermi energy of an element inside of crystal affect its fermi level?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons, crystals

If I had a substitutional crystal of nickel atoms inside of a copper fcc lattice, how would this affect the Fermi level of the material?

Comment: Most substitutional defects will shift the Fermi level in some way, the result depends on the nature of the interaction. We can see this through spectroscopy shifts. Funnily enough I actually did this the other day using XANES and NEXAFS.

Comment: What methods could one do to measure the shift in the Fermi level? I don't have access to laboratory supplies, however could a voltmeter be used with a pure crystal as a reference?

Comment: Electrochemistry uses redox reactions to create a potential difference. Although an awful lot of substitutions are redox in some way, there is an awful lot that are not, (we call these isovalent). Therefore you couldn't take advantage of a voltammeter. Normally (look at Frost-Ebsworth diagrams) Ni and Cu are in the 2+ state, therefore the substitution you mention is isovalent.